# Double integration on an array multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

In my project, the integrand is a sophisticated multiplication of arrays. I should perform a double integration on this integrand. A very simplified version of my problem can be expressed as follows:

```
def func(x,y):
    a = np.array([[x**2+2*y, y-2],[2*x+2*y, y**2-3*x]])
    return a.dot(a)
```

If I had 1d integration, I could simply use `scipy.integrate.quad_vec`. On the other hand, if my function did not contain arrays, `scipy.integrate.dblquad` could have done the job for the double integration. But I can not address any function in `scipy.integrate` that do those tasks mentioned above similtaneusly.

I tried to perform integrations one by one. I had seen this method for double integrations in handbooks.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec



def func(x,y):
    a = np.array([[x**2+2*y, y-2],[2*x+2*y, y**2-3*x]])
    return a.dot(a)

f1 = lambda y: quad_vec(func,0,1, args = (y,))
print(quad_vec(f1,0,1))
```

However my implentation raised an error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Is there any way to numerically integrate this function?

Comment: `sequence` is a `list` (or less likely a tuple or string`).  multiplication for that is "replication" which obviously can't be done with a float.  Keep track of the `type` of your variables and arguments.  Don't make assumptions, especially when you get errors.  Oh, and show the **full error** (with traceback), so you - and we - can see exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: Do you realize the `quad_vec` returns a tuple result?  Read, and in necessary reread, the docs!

Comment: @hpaulj You are right. I changed `f1` definition to `f1 = lambda y: quad_vec(func,0,1, args = (y,))[0]` and everything worked fine.